# How to retrieve object property using Dictionary in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, orm

I need a help to implement the below scenario.

```
public class CollectionOfFeilds
{
public string name {get; set;}
public Field datavalue {get; set;}
}

public class Field
{ 
public object objvalue {get; set;}
}
```

Is there any way to get the object using Dictionary ? I want to create two tables each for CollectionOfFeilds and Field class, where Field table should have two columns, [Keys] of type nvarchar(max) and [Value] of type sql_variant which can take any datatype, these data should come from dictionary. 
I read that EF doesn't support sql_variant datatype, is there any other ORM which will help me to accomplish this task. Kindly explain in detail as I am new to asp.net mvc

Comment: Still can't understand what exactly you want to implement and how it related to asp.net..

Comment: I want to create SQL tables from these c# classes such that the object property should be passed to database table as key value pair. For instance, lets say a product has many fields (there can be thousands of attributes) I want all of fields in rows instead of column.                                      var val = new {Type="Automobile", Brand="BMW", ModelDate=2016/5/12, etc}                                                                           Here [Key]=Type and [Value]=Automobile , and so on

Comment: So you are able to create table "Object" and table "ObjectProperties" with one-to-many relation. Will it solve your problem?

Comment: Also you can store values of object properies in serialized format (for example, json or xml).

Comment: Well for the object properties which is [Value] column, I want it to be sql_variant type which can store any datatype in a single column.

Comment: Right now I am unable to figure out a way to get the object in dictionary and pass it to the view and to the database. I would really appreciate if you could suggest a method to do so.